# reader.ReadString();

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

**`Я создал xml документ`**

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Information");
     xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
            XmlNode userNode;

            userNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Element1");
            userNode.InnerText = "0";
            rootNode.AppendChild(userNode);
            Debug.Log("False2");

            xmlDoc.Save("Data/Save.xml");
```

Но не могу прочитать его использую этот код

```
public void ReadInformation(){//to do check
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("Data/Save.xml");
        while (reader.Read()) {
            if(reader.IsStartElement("Element1") && !reader.IsEmptyElement) {
                Debug.Log("read.ReadString = "+reader.ReadString());
                string s = reader.ReadString();
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Почему не пердается значение в string s

Comment: Метод `ReadString()` внутри `Debug.Log` прочитал значение. Больше там этого значения нет. Поэтому сперва его читайте в переменную, а потом эту переменную используйте.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вы были правы)))